# Facebook login not working from non-home page

Tags: php, facebook, api, oauth

I have a (currently very simple) website that is utilising Facebook's "Website with Facebook Login" app setting. My problem seems simple on the face of it, but I'm unable to work it out, could someone shed any light?

My website homepage is (say) https://www.mysite.net/
 - when I log in from here using the code below, it works.

```
if(!$this->facebook->getUser())
    {
        //NOT LOGGED IN 
       $params = array(
          'scope' => 'email, publish_stream, user_photos, status_update',
          'redirect_uri' => current_url(),
        );  
        $auth_url = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl($params);  
        $auth_text = "Log In";
    } 
    else 
    {
        //LOGGED IN         
        $fbid = $this->facebook->getUser();
        $fbid = $fbid;
        $auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?confirm=1&next=".urlencode(base_url().'logout/')."&access_token=".$this->facebook->getAccessToken();
        $auth_text = "Log Out";
    }

<a href="<?=$auth_url;?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-user"></i> <?=$auth_text;?></a>
```

.. that works fine.

However, when I use the same code (and the user needs to log in) from say https://www.mysite.net/second_page/, and I use the exact above code on the second page also, the login script redirects to the Facebook Auth Dialog (great), and redirects to the redirect_uri(also great), but the user is NOT logged in to the page - ie, it gives the "Log In" dialog rather than the expected "Log Out" dialog.

Am I doing something wrong here? I would expect the facebook login dialog to work from any page off my app-specified site root. I don't want to need to redirect my users to the home page for every login, they need to be able to log in from any page of the site.

Thoughts?

Regards,
Paul G

Comment: Compare the login URLs – do they seems correct in both cases? Check what cookies your browser has accepted after login for both different ways.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Cookies are not in play in this case. It is using the FB PHP API, which pushes data into the $_SESSION array. To be sure, I've checked the cookies, and in both cases (success and failure of login, from home page and non-home page repectively) the same cookies are generated. And the loginURLs are correct in both cases, yes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented a workaround. On pages that are NOT the base URL, I've had them reference themselves in a session variable, as follows:

```
if(!$this->facebook->getUser())
{
  // Set a session var <---
  $_SESSION['redirect_state'] = current_url();
  //NOT LOGGED IN 
   $params = array(
      'scope' => 'email, publish_stream, user_photos, status_update',
      'redirect_uri' => base_url(), // <-- Changed this back to base url.
    );  
    $auth_url = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl($params);  
    $auth_text = "Log In";
} 
else 
{
    //LOGGED IN         
    $fbid = $this->facebook->getUser();
    $fbid = $fbid;
    $auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?confirm=1&next=".urlencode(base_url().'logout/')."&access_token=".$this->facebook->getAccessToken();
    $auth_text = "Log Out";
}

<a href="<?=$auth_url;?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-user"></i> <?=$auth_text;?></a>
```

Then, the login script will redirect to the app's base URL. In the base URL, I've place a little code checking for the presence of $_SESSION['redirect_state'], then kill it, then redirect:

```
// Is this a redirect from a another page's login?
    if((isset($_SESSION['redirect_state'])))
    {
        $redir_page = $_SESSION['redirect_state'];  
        unset($_SESSION['redirect_state']);
        redirect($redir_page);
        exit;
    }
```

The user is now redirected back to the page they logged in from. Because the FB user is logged in, the redirect session variable will not be set, and if the user heads home, the home page won't redirect weirdly as, again, the redirect session variable is not set.

I hope this helps someone else out. I'm surprised I haven't found anyone else talking about this issue, too :)

Comment: can u make a little clearer about the little code for the presence of $_SESSION['redirect_state']..where to place that code??

Answer (score 0):

Remove Redirection url entry from array $param(this one -> redirect_uri).
Use this option only when you want you redirect on some other page.. if you want to redirect on same page then no need to mention it, It will automatically return after login.

here is same code without redirect_uri...

```
if(!$this->facebook->getUser())
    {
        //NOT LOGGED IN 
       $params = array(
          'scope' => 'email, publish_stream, user_photos, status_update'
         );  
        $auth_url = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl($params);  
        $auth_text = "Log In";
    } `enter code here`
    else 
    {
        //LOGGED IN         
        $fbid = $this->facebook->getUser();
        $fbid = $fbid;
        $auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?confirm=1&next=".urlencode(base_url().'logout/')."&access_token=".$this->facebook->getAccessToken();
        $auth_text = "Log Out";
    }

<a href="<?=$auth_url;?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-user"></i> <?=$auth_text;?></a>
```

Comment: This does not work. Thanks for your reply though. I am using the PHP API, so removing the redirect_uri simply enables getLoginUrl() to inject the current URL (which is the non-home page, and is failing the login) into the generated URL - causing the login to redirect to itself, and fail. This is not a redirection issue, as we know they can be engineered. This is an issue with FB being unable to accept, and redirect to, a URL that is NOT the app's BASE_URL. Any ideas? Has anyone gotten a FB login dialog to work from, and redirect to, a page *other* than their web app's home page?